# What is the origin and meaning of this symbol?

Tags: symbolism

The symbol in the attached photo is on the side of a 1940s motorcycle purchased from a police vehicle auction. The symbol in question is mounted on the frame near the rear axle. Can anyone shed light on what this symbol may mean?

[image: Symbol on 40's Motorcycle]

This was originally a Harley Davidson police motorcycle. The symbol was on the motorcycle when purchased at an auction of used police vehicles. I am not sure it is Christian, but I see a cross with a shield behind it and a banner hanging below the shield. I am guessing it is a symbol used by a fraternal Christian org, maybe a policeman's org. I have added an enlarges image.

[image: Enlarged image of symbol]

Comment: I will say that in your first image (not the close-up), it appears to be some sort of **coat of arms** or **heraldic symbol**. I tried doing an actual image match of a small cut-out I took from your image, but no matches were found.  If you wish to continue the search, I suggest you search Google images for either of the phrases I emboldened above.